# Find distinct id by many row manipulations

Tags: mysql, sql

Data set looks like this:

```
ID  Rank   Case
1    1      1
1    2      0
1    3      0
2    1      0
2    2      1
2    3      0
3    1      1
3    2      0
3    3      0
```

I want to find all the IDs that has `Rank=1 Case=0, Rank=2 Case=1, Rank=3 Case=0.` In the above case, this would return `ID2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select id
from your_table
group by id
having sum(rank=1 and `case`=0) > 0
and sum(rank=2 and `case`=1) > 0
and sum(rank=3 and `case`=0) > 0
```